# Errors handling with swfupload

Tags: error-handling, swfupload

I don't figure out to do this. I started with a sample found on the download package and edited for my needs.
I made an extension validation in the php server file script, so if the extension isn't in whitelist the script exits with an error. 
I don't know how to get custom message works.

There is the php function

```
function HandleError($message) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
    echo $message;
}
```

But this return only 500 instead of $message!  This is js `uploadError()`

```
function uploadError(file, errorCode, message) {
try {
    var progress = new FileProgress(file, this.customSettings.progressTarget);
    progress.setError();
    progress.toggleCancel(false);

    switch (errorCode) {
    case SWFUpload.UPLOAD_ERROR.HTTP_ERROR:
        progress.setStatus("Errore upload: " + message);
        this.debug("Error Code: HTTP Error, File name: " + file.name + ", Message: " + message);
        break;
    case SWFUpload.UPLOAD_ERROR.UPLOAD_FAILED:
        progress.setStatus("Upload fallito.");
        this.debug("Error Code: Upload Failed, File name: " + file.name + ", File size: " + file.size + ", Message: " + message);
        break;
    case SWFUpload.UPLOAD_ERROR.IO_ERROR:
        progress.setStatus("Errore Server (IO)");
        this.debug("Error Code: IO Error, File name: " + file.name + ", Message: " + message);
        break;
    case SWFUpload.UPLOAD_ERROR.SECURITY_ERROR:
        progress.setStatus("Errore Security");
        this.debug("Error Code: Security Error, File name: " + file.name + ", Message: " + message);
        break;
    case SWFUpload.UPLOAD_ERROR.UPLOAD_LIMIT_EXCEEDED:
        progress.setStatus("Limite upload superato.");
        this.debug("Error Code: Upload Limit Exceeded, File name: " + file.name + ", File size: " + file.size + ", Message: " + message);
        break;
    case SWFUpload.UPLOAD_ERROR.FILE_VALIDATION_FAILED:
        progress.setStatus("File non valido.  Upload ignorato.");
        this.debug("Error Code: File Validation Failed, File name: " + file.name + ", File size: " + file.size + ", Message: " + message);
        break;
    case SWFUpload.UPLOAD_ERROR.FILE_CANCELLED:
        // If there aren't any files left (they were all cancelled) disable the cancel button
        if (this.getStats().files_queued === 0) {
            document.getElementById(this.customSettings.cancelButtonId).disabled = true;
        }
        progress.setStatus("Cancellato.");
        progress.setCancelled();
        break;
    case SWFUpload.UPLOAD_ERROR.UPLOAD_STOPPED:
        progress.setStatus("Sospeso.");
        break;
    default:
        progress.setStatus("Errore non gestito: " + errorCode);
        this.debug("Error Code: " + errorCode + ", File name: " + file.name + ", File size: " + file.size + ", Message: " + message);
        break;
    }
} catch (ex) {
    this.debug(ex);
}
```

If I comment out the `header()` function, it display the error in the progress bar (yay), but treat it like successed, and it's not I have to treat it with an error. With `header()` removed the js script go to `uploadSuccess` instead `uploadError`.
The documentation is really ugly and I don't find anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the header and then add `exit(0)` after `echo $message`. I think this will resolve the issue.